# Can you explain why \G in my Perl regex pattern behaves this way?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$dna = "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC";
while ($dna =~ /(\w\w\w)*?TGA/g) {  # note the minimal *?        
    print "Got a TGA stop codon at position ", pos $dna, "\n";
}
```

The answer is:

```
Got a TGA stop codon at position 18    
Got a TGA stop codon at position 23
```

Why is the position 18, but not 8? And the following 23. I'm confused how does it match? What's the detail information about the match?

But the right code is:

```
while ($dna =~ /\G(\w\w\w)*?TGA/g) {        
  print "Got a TGA stop codon at position ", pos $dna, "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
Got a TGA stop codon at position 18
```

How?

Comment: So you want the first three characters before a TGA in the string or what is confusing you exactly ?

Comment: What is `\G` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Tomalak it anchors the match to the end of the last match

Comment: But doesn't `/.../g` do that by default? I thought there were no overlapping matches in in regular expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak but there may be gaps between matches (which `\G` disallows).

Comment: Ah, of course. I didn't think about it that way.

Answer (score 6):

As @Tomalak said you don't need `*?` because it is the reason for the confusion in your situation. Here is what is going down in your first piece of code:

It sees that `(\w\w\w)*?` is reluctant *(optional)* so it skips it and tries to match `TGA` but no luck so the engine backtracks and matches a three consecutive word characters reading `ATC`, now again it tries to match `TGA` but no luck again so it reads another three consecutive `\w` and the engine has read `ATCGTT` so far.

Now it tries `TGA` again and no luck, then backtracks and reads `\w\w\w` again so now it has `ATCGTTGAA`, and now tries to find `TGA` but it has already skipped the first one when it read the last three `\w`, so this is why the engine fails to find the first `TGA` and hence fails to reports it position.

Now the engine continues in this matter until it finds the `TGA` after the three `AAA` *(if you kept going like i was doing you will see how this happens)*, and now it executes the instructions inside the the loop printing 18.

Since you have used the `/g` modifier, the next match attempt starts where the first one has ended and it fails, then it tries another match skipping a single character after the last match and so on until it matches the last `TGA` and prints 23.

So why in the second situation it only matches one position at 18, what is the effect of using the `\G` modifier ?

Well everything works the same until it finds the first match like the previous situation after the three `AAA`, then when the next match starts it tries to match `\G` which means try to match where the last match ended after the `AAATGA` and it works, then it tries to match the rest of the string but fails, but this time when the engine tries to skip a single character or two or three or so on it will always try to match `\G` first which won't happen unless if the match started at the end of the previous *(that is after `AAATGA`)* so it will keep failing, thus reporting only a single match position at 18.

Simply just remove `*?` as @Tomalak said.

Comment: Beautiful explanation.

Comment: Thanks @alanmoore for correcting those typo mistakes, I didn't notice them.

Comment: I forget to tell that the

Comment: @user2677944 What have you forgotten ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `*?` at all.

```
$dna = "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC";
while ($dna =~ /(?:\w\w\w)TGA/g) {
    print "Got a TGA stop codon at position ", pos $dna, "\n";3.    
}
```

prints

```
Got a TGA stop codon at position 8
Got a TGA stop codon at position 18
```

Note that `*?` makes the preceding atom optional, but you actually want it to be required.

- The non-capturing group (?: ...) is not really necessary. You could use a normal group.
- Another variant would be `/[TGAC]{3}TGA/g`.

Comment: I forget to tell that the purpose of the match is to combine every three words and match another three,e.g 01234567 matches 012,345,678 but not the 012,123,234 ......

Comment: There are no overlapping matches in regular expressions. I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

> Got a TGA stop codon at position 18

The reason the first match is at pos 18 and not 8 is because the match at pos 18 is the **left-most** match:

```
 (ATC) (GTT) (GAA) (TGC) (AAA) [TGA] CATGAC
  0     3     6     9     12    15   18
```

This match occurs from a start-position of zero where it can match (\w\w\w) 5 times before TGA.

But the match that results in pos 8 occurs at a start-position of 2 which can match (\w\w\w) once before TGA:

```
  AT (CGT) [TGA] ATGCAAATGACATGAC
      2     5    8
```

And regexes prefer the **left-most** match.

Adding `\G` requires the match to be anchored at the start (or following your last match).  In this case, it will match TGA only when TGA is a multiple of 3 characters from the start of the string.  Is this what you need?