Common Lisp: How to imitate the \G anchor with CL-PPCRE?
In the Perl Tutorial for regular expressions there is this example with the /g modifier:
$dna = "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC";
while ($dna =~ /(\w\w\w)*?TGA/g) {  # note the minimal *?
    print "Got a TGA stop codon at position ", pos $dna, "\n";
}

I translated it to Common Lisp like this:
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC"))
  (ppcre:do-matches (m-s m-e    ; match-start match-end
                     "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA"
                     dna
                     nil
                     :start 0 :end (length dna))
    (format t "~&;; Got a TGA stop codon at position ~d"
            m-e)))

which behaves like the Perl example:
;; Got a TGA stop codon at position 18
;; Got a TGA stop codon at position 23
NIL

From the Perl tutorial:

Position 18 is good, but position 23 is bogus. What happened?
The answer is that our regexp works well until we get past the
last real match. Then the regexp will fail to match a
synchronized TGA and start stepping ahead one character position
at a time, not what we want.
The solution is to use \G to anchor the match to the codon
alignment ...

The documentation of CL-PPCRE says

The following Perl features are (currently) not supported: ...
\G for Perl's pos() because we don't have it.

But of course I want the functionality, at least to cover the tutorial mostly complete with cl-ppcre. So, I try to figure out what happens, why the regexp will "start stepping ahead one character position" which I would not expect, so I still do not really get the functionality of regexs. (But that is what I expect of me. For now, I try to find translations to Common Lisp working for me. Then I will delve into the art of creating the regex with the desired behaviour for the respective problem to solve.)
However, first I looked at it with ppcre:do-scans:
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC"))
  (ppcre:do-scans (m-s m-e
                   r-s r-e    ; register-start register-end
                   "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA"
                   dna
                   nil
                   :start 0 :end (length dna))
    (format t "~&;; ~a ~a ~a ~a" m-s m-e r-s r-e)))

which outputs:
;; 0 18 #(12) #(15)     ; end pos 18
;; 20 23 #(NIL) #(NIL)  ; <<<< Why NIL? why start pos 20?
NIL

So naive as I am, I first tried to use this for me:
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC"))
  (ppcre:do-scans (m-s m-e
                   r-s r-e
                   "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA"
                   dna
                   nil
                   :start 0 :end (length dna))
    (if (null (elt r-s 0))
        (return)
        (format t "~&;; Got a TGA stop codon at position ~d"
                m-e))))

Which did the job.
;; Got a TGA stop codon at position 18
NIL

But I did not expect that this would be a general solution.
Adding triplets to the "DNA" changed the picture again (of course, Frankenstein):
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGACTGCTGAGTTATGAAATGCATC"))
  (ppcre:do-scans (m-s m-e
                   r-s r-e
                   "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA"
                   dna
                   nil
                   :start 0 :end (length dna))
    (format t "~&;; ~a ~a ~a ~a" m-s m-e r-s r-e)))

results in:
;; 0 18 #(12) #(15)
;; 18 30 #(24) #(27)     <<<<<< end 30
;; 31 37 #(31) #(34)     <<<<<< start 31 results in a bogus
NIL

To be sure (and with the hope to find a hint for the necessity of "stepping ahead one character") I visualised it for me like this:
;;  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17|18
;;  A  T  C  G  T  T  G  A  A  T  G  C  A  A  A  T  G  A| 
;;         |        |        |        |        |        |

;;                                      v
;; 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26|27 28 29|30<
;;  C  A  T  G  A  C  T  G  C  T  G  A| G
;;         |        |        |        | ∧ 
                                         
;;  v
;; 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44
;;  T  T  A  T  G  A| A  A  T  G  C  A  T  C
;;      |        |  |     |        |
;;  ........|-------|
;;           bogus

And since I thought, maybe I can get more information out of a longer
sequence, I tried this again:
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGACTGCTGAGTTATGAAATGCATCTGCTGAATCAAACTGAAATGAATC"))
  (ppcre:do-scans (m-s m-e
                   r-s r-e
                   "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA"
                   dna
                   nil
                   :start 0 :end (length dna))
    (format t "~&;; ~a ~a ~a ~a" m-s m-e r-s r-e)))

which resulted in:
;; 0 18 #(12) #(15)
;; 18 30 #(24) #(27)    end pos 30
;; 30 51 #(45) #(48)    <<<<<<< oops, start pos 30 and the match is correct
;; 51 66 #(60) #(63)    <<<<<<< again correct.
NIL

(Again, I wanted to be real sure and completed my visualisation. But I have no doubt that you do not want to see it again.)
This picture kept the same with an even longer "dna" of
"ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGACTGCTGAGTTATGAAATGCATCTGCTGAATCAAACTGAAATGAATCAAATGCTGACCC"

output
;; 0 18 #(12) #(15)
;; 18 30 #(24) #(27)
;; 30 51 #(45) #(48)
;; 51 66 #(60) #(63)
;; 66 78 #(72) #(75)
NIL

And I think: The corresponding effect or the imitation of the \G
anchor would be to tell ppcre:do-scans that in the case of this
search it always shall proceed in that way it does in
the last two cases with the very long strings.
But I do not get the picture right now what to do or how to tell it ppcre:do-scans and its relatives. (I also did not find the pattern for the reason why we need to "start stepping ahead one character position at a time" with "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA" yet.)
And: If I started with pos 18 -> pos 20 and pos 30 -> pos 31 went on with pos 30 -> pos 30, pos 51 -> pos 51, will I have pos 567 -> pos 566 at some length and pos 1038 -> pos 1036 and so on?
Could you help me?

EDIT:
So the answer below suggests to consider this more closely?
(let ((dna "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC"))
  (ppcre:scan "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA" dna))

=> 0, 18, #(12), #(15)

(str:substring 0 18 "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC")

=> "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGA"

(let ((dna (subseq "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC" 18))) ; -> "CATGAC"
  (ppcre:scan "(\\w\\w\\w)*?TGA" dna))

=> 2, 5, #(NIL), #(NIL)



The related question "Can you explain why \G in my Perl regex pattern behaves this way?" seems to - maybe - contain hints to find the reason for "stepping ahead", but I cannot see a hint for the solution of my understanding problem with ppcre:do-scans at the moment.
(The related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310662/can-you-explain-why-g-in-my-perl-regex-pattern-behaves-this-way?rq=2 )

I think using regex here is something inappropriate. Try this under shell, for sample: fold -w 3 <<<$dna| sed -ne '/TGA/='  show quickly 6. Then for fun: fold -w 3 <<<$dna|sed -ne '/TGA/{ =; i*3;' -e '}'| xargs | bc will show 18, But I don't know of to map a string to an array by 3 characters under lisp.

Hmmm, yes, thank you. But here the question is not "what is the most appropriate way" with the answer to prefer something else, like a literal string regex. The question is: "What is the most appropriate way to translate the Perl tutorial for regex with the means of the Common Lisp library PPCRE and in this specific case, is ppcre:do-scans and its relatives the right mean for global matching, why does it behave the way I demonstrated above and how can I use the means of the library to find the corresponding translation for the \G anchor"
Anyway, thank you for this different perspective.

Like lot of other question here, This seem an XY Problem

First of all, let's add a little to your program:
$dna = "ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGAC";
while ($dna =~ /(?:\w\w\w)*?TGA/g) {  # note the minimal *?
    print "Matched found at [$-[0],$+[0]): `$&`.\n";
}

Matched found at [0,18): `ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGA`.
Matched found at [20,23): `TGA`.

($+[0] is the same as pos($dna).)
In Perl, regex are not anchored by default. By this, I mean it will try to find a match starting at the second position if it can't find a match at the first. And it does this iteratively until it either finds a match, or every subsequent positions has been tried.
For example, the following returns true (when evaluated in scalar context) even though the string doesn't start with b.
"abc" =~ /b/   # true

Looking at your program, a match was attempted as position 18, but that failed. So it tried at position 19, which also failed. But it did succeed to find a match at position 20.
\G prevents this advancement. \G can only match where the previous match left off. To emulate \G, you will need to ensure the match starts at 18 without advancing. You could do this as follows (in Perl since I don't know Lisp):
sub gmatch_anchored {
   my $str = shift;
   my $re  = shift;
   my $pos = shift // 0;
   
   my @matches;
   while ( $pos <= length( $str ) ) {
      $str =~ /\A(?s:.{$pos})(?:$re)/
         or last;

      push @matches, [
         [ $pos, $+[0] ],
         ( map { [ $-[$_], $+[$_] ] } 1 .. $#- ),
      ];

      $pos = $+[0];
   }

   return \@matches;   
}

gmatch_anchored( $str, qr/(?:\w\w\w)*?TGA/ )

One catch. Perl prevents the same match (same starting position and same ending position) from occurring twice in a row to prevent infinite loops. The above doesn't handle this, and loops indefinitely when a pattern matches zero characters. Fixed:
sub gmatch_anchored {
   my $str = shift;
   my $re  = shift;
   my $pos = shift // 0;

   my @matches;
   my $min_len = 0;
   while ( $pos <= length( $str ) ) {
      my $min_end = $pos + $min_len;

      $str =~ /\A(?s:.{$pos})(?:$re)(?<=(?s:.{$min_end}))/
         or last;

      push @matches, [
         [ $pos, $+[0] ],
         ( map { [ $-[$_], $+[$_] ] } 1 .. $#- ),
      ];

      $min_len = $+[0] == $pos ? 1 : 0;
      $pos = $+[0];
   }

   return \@matches;   
}

gmatch_anchored( "abc", ".*?" )


Thank you very much! Especially for editing. Now I have more to figure out :-) Before I was trying harder to adopt the meaning :-)
I do not mark it as "accepted" just because I hope that a Lispy answer will arise :-) But now I have further hints to look for corresponding features I do have access to.

I don't know Lisp

I realised that ... (oh you edited again) ... you don't speak Lisp ;-) But anyway you helped me with the Perl perspective. And even if I don't know Perl it is understandable enough to get ideas. So, your Perly answer is helpful as well. Of course, an experienced Lisper can show me how to use the library more appropriately. It's the first Common Lisp library I try to understand from scratch (going beyond the built-in standard language means)  and the Perl regex tutorial helps me a lot :-)

I added an alternative that uses a look-behind

This will probably be helpful. The documentation of the library says: "The function accepts most of the regex syntax of Perl 5.8 as described in man perlre including extended features like non-greedy repetitions, positive and negative look-ahead and look-behind assertions, "standalone" subexpressions, and conditional subpatterns. "

Yeah, I just noticed that. So that approach should work for you. I deleted the original one.

Added support for lookbehinds that look before the starting position.

As a Bioinformatician, I learned a little bit Pearl and this remembered me of my first time into Bioinformatics.
Trying to match the pattern once at a time (using cl-ppcre:scan) and when matches found,
set the new start to the match-end position was the way to go.
The final result is:
(ql:quickload :cl-ppcre)
(defun gmatch-anchored (re str &optional (pos 0) (matches '()) (match-strings '()))
  "This function performs regex matching in the string `str` 
   using the pattern `re` and attempts to mimic Perl's \\G anchor 
   functionality by ensuring that each subsequent match 
   starts exactly where the previous match ended. It collects both 
   the positions of the matches and the matched strings into 
   separate lists, which are returned as the final result."
  (multiple-value-bind 
    (match-start match-end registers-start registers-end) 
    (cl-ppcre:scan re (subseq str pos))
    (if (and match-start          ;; any match found?
             (zerop match-start)) ;; anchoring!
        (gmatch-anchored re
                         str
                         (+ pos match-end)
                         (cons (list (+ pos match-start)
                                     (+ pos match-end)
                                     (loop for x across registers-start
                                           collect (when x
                                                     (+ pos x)))
                                     (loop for x across registers-end
                                           collect (when x
                                                     (+ pos x))))
                               matches)
                         (cons (list (subseq str
                                             (+ pos match-start)
                                             (+ pos match-end))
                                     (loop for register-start across registers-start
                                           for register-end across registers-end
                                           collect (if (and register-start register-end)
                                                       (subseq str
                                                               (+ pos register-start)
                                                               (+ pos register-end))
                                                       '())))
                               match-strings))
        (list (nreverse matches) (nreverse match-strings)))))

(gmatch-anchored "(((\\w\\w\\w)*?)TGA)" 
"ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGACATGACTGCTGAGTTATGAAATGCATCTGCTGAATCAAACTGAAATGAATC")
#|
=> (((0 18 (0 0 12) (18 15 15)) 
     (18 30 (18 18 24) (30 27 27))
     (30 51 (30 30 45) (51 48 48)) 
     (51 66 (51 51 60) (66 63 63)))
    (("ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGA" ("ATCGTTGAATGCAAATGA" "ATCGTTGAATGCAAA" "AAA"))
     ("CATGACTGCTGA" ("CATGACTGCTGA" "CATGACTGC" "TGC"))
     ("GTTATGAAATGCATCTGCTGA" ("GTTATGAAATGCATCTGCTGA" "GTTATGAAATGCATCTGC" "TGC"))
     ("ATCAAACTGAAATGA" ("ATCAAACTGAAATGA" "ATCAAACTGAAA" "AAA"))))
|#

Crucial for the anchoring behavior is the condition (zerop match-start), because it allows only matches to count which really start from the last match's end. And through the (\\w\\w\\w)*? then the search stays "in-frame".
Adding the current position to the (relative) match positions, e.g. (+ pos match-start), (+ pos match-end) etc. is necessary to get the absolute positions within the string.
The registers-start an registers-end are vectors - thus across has to be used when looping. And since non-matches result in NIL match values, one has to anticipate them with a (when x ...) to avoid NIL-not-a-number errors - when doing (+ pos x).
In case of match-start, a NIL means no further match found starting from the anchoring position - which ends the recursion.

Oh, this is great! Thank you. I was away for a while since and had no time to go on with this. So, I first will have to recap the whole thing before I can comprehend your example and explanation. It is so difficult, if you are "dancing on several wedding parties". When you come back to the first, you have to recognise the bride again, which needs a little while. But it is wonderful to know, that you provided me a key to my memory. When I come back to it, I will likely set the green hook. Best regards to Basel from Berlin.

You are welcome! Now I am more in Zürich area :) .
Did you modified meanwhile your question? It seems to me much longer.
But it seems now, cl-ppcre:do-scans does it already? Or what was the point of the second long part of your question? It was so long ago that I forgot myself - especially I am not sure any more whether I understood your question correctly - haha.
